# Fill in Input Field by Clicking Link with JQuery

Tags: jquery

How might someone fill in an input field with some text using jquery by clicking that text?

The text is generated dynamically so the value is not know ahead of time.

For example with:

```
<input id="a_input_id" type="text">
<a href="#" class="special_field_link">@r.SpecialField<a>
```

When someone clicks that link the text field with be populated with the value of `@r.SpecialField`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

HTML:

```
<input id="a_input_id" type="text">
<a href="#" class="special_field_link">@r.SpecialField<a>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $('.special_field_link').live('click', function() {
        $("#a_input_id").val($(this).html());
    });
});
```

Also, you can use .text() instead of .html() as listed in this answer: [Fill in Input Field by Clicking Link with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653950/fill-in-input-field-by-clicking-link-with-jquery/5653982#5653982)

Running Sample: http://fiddle.jshell.net/s8nUh/

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$(".special_field_link").click(function(){
 $("#a_input_id").val($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a.special_field_link').live('click', function(e){
    $('#a_input_id').val(this.innerHTML);
    return false; // to prevent default
});
```