# Fill input field, with twig value using jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony, twig

I've been searching for a while with no luck.

I know my question looks mundane, and it has plenty (as in hundreds) of answers out in google and here, yet, still my problem seems far from solved.

I have the following problem, I need to fill an input field, with a value from silex variables in a twig file.

the form is as follows:

```
<span>Author: </span>
<input type="text" name="author" id="author" 
{% if user.getAuthorName %}value="{{user.getAuthorName}}"{% endif %} />
<span><a href="#" id="filler">Use your own username</a></span>
```

and the js code is:

```
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('#filler').live('click', function() {
      $("#author").val($("#author").text("{{user.getFirstName}} {{user.getLastName}}"));
    });
});
</script>
```

the problem I'm having is, the code actually works, yet still, when i click, it fills the field with

```
[object Object]
```

instead of the actual value of the 2 variables

I've tried changing it to a hidden field with an id, and setting the variables as value, and using
     .text($("#idfield").val())

still no luck, still fills the values with

```
[object Object]
```

has any of you any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: `input` has no method `text()` and why're you still using `live`?

Comment: im using this as reference [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5653950/fill-in-input-field-by-clicking-link-with-jquery/5653982#5653982)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the double declaration:

```
$("#author").val("{{user.getFirstName}} {{user.getLastName}}");
```

Comment: indeed thank you @Dasein A

this did the trick
`<script>
  $(function(){
    $('#filler').live('click', function() {
      $("#author").val("{{user.getFirstName}} {{user.getLastName}}");
    });
});
</script>`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bit cleaned up version of your code with no `live` as it's deprecated/removed.

```js
$(function() {
    $('#filler').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        //If your JS is parsed as a twig template then, you could use
        $("#author").val("{{user.getFirstName}} {{user.getLastName}}");
        //and remove the data-full-name from your HTML

        //If not, keep the data-full-name and use:
        $("#author").val($("#author").data("fullName"));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span>Author: </span>
<input data-full-name="{{user.getFirstName}} {{user.getLastName}}" type="text" name="author" id="author" value="{% if user.getAuthorName %}{{user.getAuthorName}}{% endif %}" />
<span><a href="#" id="filler">Use your own username</a></span>
```